# Dynamically add new column to MySQL in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Say I have a class that holds user info

User.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    //User Data

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
}
```

In front end page admin can update Bio Dynamically by defining new field. Say clicking on `+` button he can add new field called middle name, age or address, etc.

> P.S. It is kind of admin privilege and number of updates runtime will be limited and hence no issue of creating unlimited fields.

How can I address this dynamic addition of entity in MySQL using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

You might add new fields using a custom map, for example:

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "custom_fields")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "field")
    private Map<String, String> customFields;
```